# How to set transaction to readOnly in @query annotation?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement a system where readOnly Query will go to slave db.

For following query, my code is working fine ie. read's are going to slave db.

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
User findById(String Id);
```

But its not working with following native query. I am just trying to find, how can we set transaction to readOnly with @Query annotation

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(value = "SELECT t.role_name FROM roles t where t.id in :roles AND t.status = 'ACTIVE'" ,nativeQuery = true)
public List<String> findRoleIn(@Param("roles") List<UUID> roles);
```

Comment: How did you come to know it is not working ? Are you getting any exception ?